# Reading from a csv file, appending to a list based on conditional

Tags: r

New to `r` and I think I understand how to read from a `csv` file, but what I'm not sure of is how `r` constructs its data models so I'm getting confused when trying to create a list based off of some condition. Here's my code which I'm calling from another script...

```
getData <- function(){
  #grabs the *whole* data frame, but we only want specific rows/columns...
  csvData <- read.csv(file="..//database2.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")

  #only return the columns/rows we're interested in
  returnData <- data[c(3:1816),c(4,11)]  #data[rows,columns]
  returnData
}



pacOnly <- function(data){
  lst <- list()
  xR = nrow(data)
  i <- 1
    for(r in 1:xR){
      if(is.na(data[r,1])){
        next
      }
      if(data[r,1] == "PAC"){
        tmp <- list(dat=data[r,])
        lst[i] <- tmp
        i <- i + 1
      }      
    }
  print(lst)
}
```

However, when I print my `lst` object it looks like this (shortened)...

```
[[393]]
     Location N2N6
1798      PAC    X

[[394]]
     Location N2N6
1799      PAC    X
```

What I would like to see/create (it's likely I'm misunderstanding things) is...

```
[[393]]
     PAC X
[[394]]
     PAC X
```

..etc, so that I can populate a UI component later.

Comment: (1) Growing objects as you do in `pacOnly` is very slow, (2) Why not simply subset the data frame you read in in one line?, (3) Why does the ultimate result need to be a list and not just a data frame?

Comment: (1) Good to know, (2) I need to look into that, still trying to figure `r` out, (3) It doesn't *need* to be a list, but I'm used to python so I just assumed... I'll look into the subsetting. Thank you!

Comment: For (2) you'll want to do something using `%in%` to avoid gotcha's with `==`'s behavior with `NA` values. Maybe `dat$Location %in% "PAC"`.

Comment: Yeah, I just did a subset of the data and...wow...so much cleaner. The output seems accurate, but I'll definitely take your `%in%` suggestion as well. Thanks, @joran !